# How do I set a rule that moves emails sent to a distribution group I'm part of over to a folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, exchange, rules

How do I go about setting this up? I've tried setting a To condition and then typing the distribution list address but it didn't work. I'm guessing it's because To is for emails I've sent?

Comment: Open Outlook, Rules (Main Tab), Create Rule.  Click on Advanced.  There are a lot of options.  Groups does not seem to appear there.  See in the name or Address book options help.  Address book should contain the distribution group.

Comment: Didn't work - thanks for trying

Comment: I am not sure, then.  It seemed to me that you could use Address Book, then Edit it (bottom windows) to include the distribution group.   But if not, then I don't know.

Comment: Ok, I got it working - Weird thing though, I had to setup the rule using Outlook on Windows instead of my Mac. When I went to edit the working rule on mac to see how it was setup, it looked the same as how I set it up before.

Comment: So does my added comment provide an answer ?   Or did you find a different way ?

Comment: Yes and no - no because I had already tried what you asked me to do, but it didn't work. Yes, in that it reminded me that there are loads more options available on windows than on mac.